# CakePHP - How can I edit a field that has been returned from DB?

Tags: cakephp

Sorry for a simple question, but I'm struggling to type in the right words to find my solution online.

In my edit function in my Events Controller, I want change the format of the Start date that is returned. Here is my attempt

```
if (empty($this->data)) {
        $this->data = $this->Event->read(null, $id);
        $this->data['Event']['start'] = $this->date('d-m-Y H:i A', strtotime($this->data['Event']['start']));
    }
```

Again apologies, hopefully someone can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to perform this in your Event model using the callback method [afterFind](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#afterfind). Checkout [this link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#afterfind) for the official documentation that shows you a typical example of what you need in this question.

Comment: @user2896819 Very nice. Please sign it as an answer.